# typescript conditional types inner types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following type defined:

```
export type Limited = {
    multiple: boolean;
    trunk: Limited['multiple'] extends true ? true : false;
};
```

I want the `trunk` property to be limited my the `multiple` property. The current approach makes `trunk` to always be `false`.

I can't fathom why is that, and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type you've written says to do a type calculation based on `Limited['multiple']`'s type. That type is `boolean`. Does `boolean` extend from `true`? No, it doesn't (`true` extends from `boolean`, but not the other way around). As a result, `trunk` gets the type `false`.

If you're trying to say that `multiple` and `trunk` must either both be `true`, or both be `false`, then you'd do that like this:

```
export type Limited = {
  multiple: true;
  trunk: true;
} | {
  multiple: false;
  trunk: false;
}
```

Or alternatively you could use a generic:

```
export type Limited<T extends boolean> = {
  multiple: T,
  trunk: T
}
```